# How can I keep a coupling nut aligned with its bolt?

Tags: furnace, fastener, filter

F25\F20 Westwood oil furnace filter housing.

This should come from the factory with that nut very tight on the lower bolt. To replace the filter element you remove upper bolt, remove the can, change the filter element, reassemble & replace upper bolt. Those are the instructions and there are many YouTube videos showing this.

It seems to me that if upper bolt was over tightened, then that might cause the nut to come off the lower bolt the next time upper bolt is removed to change the element. I think this is bad design. Still, I found no one else posting issues.

A replacement worked fine, but it leaked where can seats against upper red piece. So I had to tighten the upper bolt twice to stop leak (yes there is rubber gasket between). I hope nut stays on lower bolt when I change the element next year

I now have 2 extra units and I'd like to assemble as spares. I've tried but I can't keep the nut exactly centered when tightening it onto lower bolt, which means that upper bolt won't thread in. Ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most filters are only suppose to be tighten enough to stop leaking.  Over tightening would be abuse.

Comment: That's a lot of ranting for a question with very little substance. Please [edit] your question to get rid of the first 2/3 or so of the rant, then use the site's built in image hosting facility to embed the images directly in your question. Remember, the easier it is for us to figure out what's going on, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: I'm not clear on the actual problem. If you snug down the sleeve nut, then add the upper bolt, what can go wrong? It appears that the lower bolt is fairly short, so it can't really end up too far into the nut.

Comment: Most filters of that type, getting stuff to line up is more feel since you are doing it blind.  The bottom should be hand tighten plus a bit, somewhere between a 1/4 to one turn.  The top should be easy, but a few have been lucky they were not toss out of a window.

Comment: "i cant keep the nut exactly centered when tightening it onto lower bolt" - that's the backwards way to do it. Needle nose : hold the nut pointing straight up. Turn the can upside down. Now *screw the little bolt into the nut* that you know is pointing straight up even though you can't see it. You're watching the head of the bolt to know its threads are pointing straight down.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the split lock washer should retain the nut, but if it doesn't, thread locking compound, a.k.a. Loctite<sup>™</sup>, should do. I'd probably go with the removable variety because it's more useful in your tool kit, but use a good dose of it on the lower bolt.

If we're talking about *alignment* of the top of the sleeve nut with the upper bolt, here are two strategies that come to mind:

- Snug the nut down on the lower bolt, then simply tilt it into a centered position. The bottom of the filter housing should bend fairly easily to accommodate.
- Thread the nut onto the lower bolt, but leave it slightly loose. Now assemble the filter and hold both bolts, feeling for alignment. Tightening the bolts should now be possible.

Comment: The blue is "easily" removable. The red requires heat to remove. I'm not sure if there are other colors of Loctite™. Different brands may have different colors. YMMV. +1

Comment: Yeah, I don't go by (or refer to) color. For one thing it's unintuitive so I'll probably get it wrong.

Comment: Unless that coupling nut is exactly straight up (centered), the upper bolt wont thread in after its dropped thru the center hole of the lid. Pic 3 that bolt is not in center of upper lid.

Comment: That aspect of the problem wasn't clear from your question. You're apparently talking about _angle_, not position. "Straight" might be a better choice of words than "centered". I took that to mean at the bottom attachment point. The problem is that the bulk of your post deals with another part of the issue, so that was misleading.